# In ndk-r10 release, do we need to run ndk-build if already add-native-support?

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I am learning NDK environment, there is lot of tutorial/example to teach on building a simple design which using NDK/JNI.

Some say we need to run ndk-build to generate the .so file, some say no need, just link the project with "add native support". Is anyone know what is the method we should use for ndk-r10 release?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**r10** does not change the rules of the game. You still need to run `ndk-build` to have the**.so** files created (and copied to correct directory).

If in eclipse (to be more precise, in ADT) you added native support to your project, then eclipse will launch `ndk-build` as the first steel of building the project, so you do not need to launch `ndk-build` manually.

You can see and modify parameters to `ndk-build` when you open project properties in eclipse. You can see output of `ndk-build` in **Console** view in eclipse. Errors and Warnings will also be seen in **Problems** view.

Some people have reported that they could not *add native support* with latest download of the ADT bundle. Manual update often resolves this issue, search more  about this on SO.

Comment: Hence, the ndk-build already automatically run when i select "add native suppport"? It still there, just get wrap around.

Comment: My suggestion is to always check that. As I explained above, this is not hidden too far away.